# How correctly cast or wrap the type of an event handler? (delegate vs. EventArgs in +=)

Tags: c#, events, declaration

I have a cross-platform `class GPSPosition` containing the fields we need from a GPS unit.

On Xamarin.Android I am using Xamarin.Mobile's Xamarin.Geolocation package, which has an event handler `Geolocator.PositionChanged`, to which can be added methods that match this signature: `void MyMethod( object sender, PositionEventArgs e )`. That is, given a declared `Geolocator locator`, this compiles:  `locator.PositionChanged += MyMethod;`.

That is working fine, until I re-work my solution to use our cross-platform `GPSPosition`, instead of the Xamarin `PositionEventArgs` -- which is:

```
public class PositionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

To "convert" usage of `Position` to `GPSPosition`, this works:

```
public delegate void GPSPositionDeleg( GPSPosition position );

// Convert Position to GPSPosition.
GPSPosition ToGPSPosition( Position pos ) {
    ....
}

public void Start( GPSPositionDeleg positionDeleg )
{
    Locator.PositionChanged += ( sender, e ) =>
        positionDeleg( ToGPSPosition( e.Position ) );
}
```

But now I want to store that event handler?  delegate? in a local variable, so I can REMOVE it later:

```
delegate void PositionEventDeleg( object sender, PositionEventArgs e );

PositionEventDeleg MyPositionEventDeleg;

public void Start( GPSPositionDeleg positionDeleg )
{
    MyPositionEventDeleg = ( sender, e ) =>
            positionDeleg( ToGPSPosition( e.Position ) );
    Locator.PositionChanged += MyPositionEventDeleg;
}
```

That gives compile error `Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type LiveCaddie.GPSEngine.PositionEventDeleg to System.EventHandler<Xamarin.Geolocation.PositionEventArgs>` on line `Locator.PositionChanged += MyPositionEventDeleg;`.

BUT I don't want to pass in a PositionEventArgs. I want to pass in a method that takes PositionEventArgs as one of its parameters. The compiler did the desired conversion automatically when I put the lambda "inline", so it is possible -- I just don't know the correct (declaration syntax, cast, or wrapper?) to do what the compiler does, and store that in a variable.

What is the correct definition of `PositionEventDeleg`?  That is, a type in which I can save the lambda to pass to `PositionChanged += ...`, for later use in `PositionChanged -= ...`

Answer (score 1):

First, I was confused about the meaning of `EventHandler`. I thought the field `PositionChanged` was the EventHandler, but it seems that the methods added to it are EventHandlers.

Correct definition, instead of previous `PositionEventDeleg MyPositionEventDeleg;`, is:

```
EventHandler<PositionEventArgs> MyPositionEventHandler;
```

Then can store the lambda into that:

```
MyPositionEventHandler = ( sender, e ) => positionDeleg( ToGPSPosition( e.Position ) );
Locator.PositionChanged += MyPositionEventHandler;
```

---

As I specified, one can now elsewhere do:

```
Locator.PositionChanged -= MyPositionEventHandler;
```

Or more rigorously:

```
if (MyPositionEventHandler != null) {
    Locator.PositionChanged -= MyPositionEventHandler;
    MyPositionEventHandler = null;
}
```

To avoid a null exception if `MyPositionEventHandler` was never set, and to make it clear that `MyPositionEventHandler` has been removed.

Comment: NOTE: I can't accept my own answer for two days; apologies if you are reading this later, and I have forgotten to go back and accept it.